# NetStream error callback, peer to peer

Tags: netstream, adobe-cirrus, soundcloud-stratus

I am pretty new , I know this place is really strict and is for the well of the forum...

So please forgive if my question is not appropriate..

I have a chat application using node.js , the user request cam with the partner this create a flash object with his cam and send his stratus id to the partner.. all good so far, but when the user that originated the request is no longer connected before the partner click on a link with the originator stratusid of the request...

The originator is not longer transmitting his cam, so that stratus id is not longer valid..

But the receiver click anyway starting his cam, but with no partner that originated the request..

```
receiveStream = new NetStream(netConnection,  hisStratusID);
```

since hisStratusID is not longer valid broadcast id, I thought NetStream would return an error code.. but no it doesn't..

Also I tried to see if I could catch the error using this function to see what Net_STATUS would bring but it doesn't fired...

```
receiveStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, receiveHandler);

private function receiveHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void  {
Alert.show(event.info.code);
}
```

I m learning so there must be something i am doing complete wrong..

regards and appreciate your help